# Case insensitive/Case preserving Monetdb tables

Tags: case-sensitive, case-insensitive, monetdb

Can I set monetdb to be case insensitive (but case preserving) ?

I am aware that workarounds exist: For example using `ilike` for search, and using `lower` in `group by` clauses but, especially in the latter case, the performance degradation is significant, especially in large datasets.

I wonder if there is a way to get case insensitive/case preserving tables in monetdb.